# UWP Community ToolKit OneDrive Service Error AADSTS65005

Tags: onedrive, adal, windows-community-toolkit

When attempting to access "Work or School Account" using the UWP CT OneDrive Service in my UWP store registered app, the Connecting to a service dialog returns -

**AADSTS65005: The application " required resource access list does not contain applications discoverable by 'https://api.office.com/discovery/'.**

The app is setup in the Application Registration Portal under Converged applications. Native Application added under Platforms. MicrosoftGraph permissions Files.ReadWrite.All. Live SDK Support is checked.

Microsoft Account access works fine. I receive the same error message when I 
attempt the connection using UWP Community Toolkit Sample App - OneDrive Service sample page. Microsoft Account access works fine there as well.

This leads me to believe there is an issue with the app portal profile. Can anyone enlighten me further as to exactly what the error message is trying to tell me? - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is a missing registration inside your Azure portal that is underlying your o365 account.

In general your application requires this *only* for "One Drive For Business", therefore it works with 'Microsoft Account" One Drive.

It is mentioned in a side note on the One Drive SDK library Readme:
"For applications targeting OneDrive for Business call the class method [ODClient setActiveDirectoryAppId: redirectURL:] with specified  and . Note: the redirect URL must match the redirect URL that you specified in the Azure Management Portal."

This is a multi-step procedure and is called "application registration" and you need to do the following steps:

1) Enter your o365 administration console and go to "Admin centers -> Azure AD". You basically enter Azure settings now.

2) Inside this special Azure view, go to "Azure Active Directory" -> "app registrations". Inside here create a new app by clicking on "new application registration".

From there you need to first create the app and most importantly insert the "sign-on URL" that was generated inside the "Application Registration Portal". After the app was created, you need to wait a bit (for me it was 10mins) until the app shows up in the list of "app registrations".

Once the app is registered you need to use another method to authenticate, see the text I copied from the SDK manual above: you need to use "setActiveDirectoryAppId" with a ***_new_ generated ID*** from the "app registrations" menu. This was the most confusing fact to learn for me! Instead of using the ID from the "Application registration portal", you need to provide this "application ID" from the Azure registration.

NOTE:
On top of that you can control the access rights for the application inside your Azure tenant. This is done by going to the "app registrations" list and click on the app and then on "settings". This overrules all other settings made anywhere else.

Good luck (I mean this in motivational way just as if talking to a soldier that was sent on a 'mission impossible' :-)).